# Windows 10 System backup

Tags: windows, backup, external, restore, drive

So a while back I made a backup image of my hard drive and put it on an external drive. Then someone stole my laptop so I no longer have that computer so is there away to restore without having the original computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249694/how-to-restore-a-windows-installation-or-move-it-to-different-hardware) it says that you can recover your data on other physical machine with the same configuration as your last one. Hope this helps..